# Wordpress disable text-wrapping under image

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here is the current issue:
[image]

I want to make it so the text never goes under the image. But this is wordpress, and I want a solution that will work for every post. So a CSS solution would be best or a PHP solution? I do not choose what Wordpress puts in divs and paragraphs.

Here is the code:

```
<p>
  <a href="http://amazon.com">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-281" src="http://dock.com//Be_here_now_ram_dass.jpg" alt="Be Here Now Ram Dass" width="137" height="138" />
  </a>
  This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
</p>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.entry-content p {
    font-size: 16px!important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a img.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
```

How do I fix this? If it's a PHP solution please explain thoroughly where to put it, etc. Thanks!

Comment: The solution is indeed a CSS one. As such, please post your relevant CSS -- we can't answer this question without it.

Comment: @ObsidianAge added but there's really not much.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the paragraph text in a block element and set it to `overflow: auto` so that the inline content doesn't flow out and wrap around the floated element.

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.content {
  font-size: 3rem;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="http://amazon.com">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-281" src="http://dock.com//Be_here_now_ram_dass.jpg" alt="Be Here Now Ram Dass" width="137" height="138" />
  </a>
  <span class="content">
  This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: But because this is wordpress, i'd have to add <span> tags everytime with every element I want to work this way. I want wordpress to automatically wrap text in span.